# hi guis iwant to help me

Tags: tables, sectioning, formatting

[image]

indeed help me in this problem when I write new subsection enter as shown in table belwo

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid your posting appears to have become garbled and that it hence is, at present, nearly incomprehensible. Please rephrase the posting and take the time to explain what exactly the problem is.

Comment: Better yet, include enough code for a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) into your question.

Comment: Now, 3 downvotes (as of now) is really too much. We had worse posts that weren't downvoted (that much)

Comment: Probably you want to use `\begin{table*}...\end{table*}` instead of `\begin{table}...\end{table}`. The former will span two columns.

Comment: Hi and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Agreed, three is too much. But this question *is* unclear.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: True, but now it's four already

Comment: @MartinSchröder - It looks like Heiko has come up with a good guess -- and an even better answer -- as to what the OP's needs are.

Comment: @Mico: I *hate* such guesses - they teach posters like Mohammed that totally unclear questions work.

Answer (score 7):

The text seems to be set in two-column mode. Then the star form of the float environments use both columns at the top or bottom of the page, example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a5paper,hmargin=10mm,vmargin=10mm,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \textcolor{gray}{\rule{12cm}{6cm}}
  \caption{Table too large}
\end{table}

\begin{table*}
  \textcolor{gray}{\rule{12cm}{6cm}}
  \caption{Table spanning both columns}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[2-6]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Page 1]

> [image: Page 2]